# PhoneGap Javascript Limits?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I'm looking to create a cross platform Mobile App and have been looking into Developing using PhoneGap. I'm an amateur programmer and most of my knowledge is in ASP.Net and C#.

Will only being able to use HTML, CSS and Javascript with PhoneGap limit me to specific functionality of my App? and would migrating to HTML5 help in adding more functionality to an App?

I'm looking to be able to Populate Drop-Downs from a Database, Add/Edit/Delete Items from a Database, Create Reports Ect...

Comment: You can use HTML5 stuff in PhoneGap apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only real limitation as far as data access goes is that you're limited to an SQLite database, which to be honest isn't much of a limitation since it performs great for single-user access.

The short of it is that you have access to a database from within your app, so you can do whatever you need to.  The tools are HTML & JS as opposed to C# with some graphics layer, so doing things like creating graphs is quite different, but it's all possible.

Also note that depending on what your app is doing, PhoneGap is one of several solutions.  If you want a "native" look/feel, consider TitaniumUI -- it takes common code (still JS) and pushes it through some translation layers to create native UI components.

Comment: Good answer overall (upvoted), however I'll add that you have more than just SQLite offline storage options on the device with PhoneGap. Most platforms also support a simple key-value store in JavaScript (dubbed localStorage or DOMstorage). As well, communicating with existing web services (be it WCF or other server-side service layers) is all possible via JavaScript and XHR. Synchronization with online databases, rendering lists/drop-downs, all that stuff is possible in PhoneGap.